# Not Sure What to Iterate With Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm having a problem iterating a crawl using scrapy. I am extracting a title field and a content field. The problem is that I get a JSON file with all of the titles listed and then all of the content. I'd like to get {title}, {content}, {title}, {content}, meaning I probably have to iterate through the parse function. The problem is that I cannot figure out what element I am looping through (i.e., `for x in [???]`) Here is the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import SitemapSpider

from Foo.items import FooItem


class FooSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "foo"
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.foo.com/sitemap.xml']
    #sitemap_rules = [


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = [
        item = FooItem()
        item['title'] = hxs.select('//span[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()
        item['content'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="articletext"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath queries returns all titles and all contents on the page. I suppose you can do:

```
titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()
contents = hxs.select('//div[@class="articletext"]/text()').extract()

for title, context in zip(titles, contents):
    item = FooItem()
    item['title'] = title
    item['content'] = context
    yield item
```

But it is not reliable. Try to perform xpath query that return block with `title` and `content` inside. If you showed me xml source I'd help you.

```
blocks = hxs.select('//div[@class="some_filter"]')
for block in blocks:
    item = FooItem()
    item['title'] = block.select('span[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()
    item['content'] = block.select('div[@class="articletext"]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

I'm not sure about xpath queries but I think idea is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `HtmlXPathSelector`. Scrapy already has built-in XPATH selector. Try this:

```
blocks = response.xpath('//div[@class="some_filter"]')
for block in blocks:
    item = FooItem()
    item['title'] = block.xpath('span[@class="headline"]/text()').extract()[0]
    item['content'] = block.xpath('div[@class="articletext"]/text()').extract()[0]
    yield item
```